# Webpack - dynamic require and paths

Tags: javascript, webpack

My webpack.config file looks like this

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './app'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: '[name]-bundle.js'
    }
};
```

I have some dynamic requires that look like this

```
function loadModule(modName, cb, onErr){
    if (modName == 'contacts') require(['../modules/contacts/contacts', 'html!../modules/contacts/contacts.htm'], cb);
    else if (modName == 'tasks') require(['../modules/tasks/tasks', 'html!../modules/tasks/tasks.htm'], cb);
    else onErr();
}
```

Which work great.  I'm seeing `1.1-bundle.js` and `2.2-bundle.js` getting **added to my build folder**.

The problem is, when these dynamic requires are triggered, I'm seeing 404s in my network tab, since webpack is trying to load 1-1.bundle.js from the root of my project, instead of the build folder where I told webpack to put it.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to set the [public path](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath)- basically, you tell webpack where on your webserver it will find the built files, which for you seems to the the build folder.

```
{
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: '[name]-bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/build/',
    },
}
```